# Modal background mask does not appear when i open the modal for the second time

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using an angular bootstrap modal.The modal has angular data table in the modal body and close button in the modal footer.The issue i was facing was that once i click on close button,the modal does disappear but screen remains grayed out and inaccessible.So,i included the below code.

```
 $('#modal-id').modal('hide');
            $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
            $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```

After adding this,the modal and the background works fine when i open and close it for the first time but when i open the modal for next time,the gray background does not appear.
Any insight appreciated.

My controller is :

```
$scope.modalPop = function(){
        $scope.modalOverlay = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'url',
            scope: $scope,
            animation: false,
            windowClass: 'overlay-lg'
        });
    };

$scope.modalClose = function() {
        $scope.modalOverlay .close();
        $('#modal-id').modal('hide');
        $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
        $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
    }
```

where modalClose is the function on ng-click for close button in modal footer.

Comment: I've had something similar in the past few days. Can you create a plunkr to show off the problem?

Comment: Egads. Consider http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal to avoid DOM manipulation in your controller. More on that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Comment: Doing DOM manipulation from controller is bad pattern..DON'T do that & why you are removing `modal-backdrop`?

Comment: PankajParkar I did that fix because initially the gray background was not getting disappear on click of close button.

Comment: @user2138675 Thats cool do add that as an answer

Comment: @Pankaj but i want the modal-backdrop class to get added to DOM again when the modal opens.Tried with append and detach but its not working.